# Prevent request to get data from json file while JSON file updating

Tags: java, javascript, php, c, json

We have seen lot of applications who are working with JSON file but i have a case study of which i want to get solution.

Let us see ...

1. a app is working with json file which gets requests from million users and every second thousands of requests has been completed.
2. JSON file is updated by admin panel every minute or second or specific time frame.
3. what will be behaviour of JSON file while request has been received to access JSON file and open for update from admin at same time (i have read it that JSON file will be fetched in readable mode.)
4. Let JSON file is writing using some script and its process is third of a second than what will be behaviour while 50% file has been updated.

   **Either file will be given with new written content when process completed or when it was partially updated?**

Comment: You should read-up on read, write locks. They are designed to specifically address clobbering of information with multiple writers.

Comment: Dont use files as transactional storage.

Comment: As @eckes said - don't use files. Use databases, and encode the result to json.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with locking, just use [`rename()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename).

Assuming you're running on an OS where a `rename()` is an atomic operation, create a **new** file, say "/data/file/name.json.new", then when that's complete, rename the file.  In C that would look like this:

`rename( "/data/file/name.json.new", "/data/file/name.json" );`

This way, any process opening "/data/file/name.json" will always see a consistent data file.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan - That would depend on how much control you have over the file-writing process.  Your original question doesn't give that information.  You can always write your own server-side code to do that, though that might require a lot of work depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, by what you describe, you want a service that applies operations on a file server-side.

You should though avoid taking the responsibility of Creating, Readind, Updating and Deleting ([CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)), as you will have troubles on preserving principles such as Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability ([ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)), while there are systems doing that for you, the Database Management Systems.
In simple words, scenarios like what you describe should be a responsibility of a DBMS and **not** yours.

You probably need a NoSQL DBMS, that responsible for the CRUD operations of your database - which can be file-based in a JSON format and other forms, preserving ACID always (or almost always, but this is probably something you will learn on searching on it). [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) is a great example of such system.

Because you mentioned JSON, please take into consideration that it is another story to transfer the data, and another to store them. I suggest that you use the JSON format for requests & responses, but explore other options in storage. For instance, even a Relational DBMS that uses SQL can be good for you, it always depends on your needs. You might just need to form (encode & decode) the data in JSON format wherever received or sent to each client.

Take a look [here](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-resources/what-is-no-sql) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. @Nick its really enhanced my programming approach.